# Typescript how to search 2d array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am working on a 2d array and I was wondering if there was a faster way to search though the array without using a nested for loop.

Below is what I currently have:

```
    dataArray: Array<Array<details>> = [
      [{result: true, context: {info: "stuff"}}, {result: false, context: {info: "more stuff"}}, ...],
      [{result: false, context: {info: "hi"}}, {result: true, context: {info: "more stuff"}}, ...],
      [{result: false, context: {info: "bye"}}, {result: false, context: {info: "more stuff"}}, ...],
      [{result: true, context: {info: "none"}}, {result: true, context: {info: "more stuff"}}, ...],
    ];

     for (let i = 0; i < this.dataArray.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < this.dataArray[i].length; j++) {
         if (this.dataArray[i][j].context.info === "hi") {
           console.log("item located in array");
        }
       }
      }
```

Is there a faster way to search through this data or should I just use the double for loop?

Comment: If you want to speed up repeated searches, you can create a Set with all context info strings.

Comment: I think you can use "some" to avoid the inner for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some but I don't know if it's more efficient